# Bash: File matching pattern works on Ubuntu but not on OS X

Tags: regex, bash

Let's say I have the following two files in my directory

```
- test.yaml
- test.yml
```

On Ubuntu, the following bash command lists both the files:

```
$ find .  -regex '.*\.ya?ml'
./test.yaml
./test.yml
```

However, on OS X the same command does not list any file:

```
$ find .  -regex '.*\.ya?ml'
```

My question, what is the regular expression pattern that can passed to `-regex` param, so the command works on both platforms?

Comment: Does `find .  -regex '.*\.ya\?ml'` work?

Comment: It does not work on either platforms.

Comment: hmmm....being Extended regex pattern, thought escaping `?` would do it..as `GNU find` sues `emacs` style regex is not helping..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` available on OSX requires `-E` for supporting extended regular expressions. On OSX following will work:

```
find -E .  -regex '.*\.ya?ml'
```

Following will also work on OSX without needing extended regex:

```
find .  -regex '.*\.ya\{0,1\}ml'
```

**EDIT:** If you want a common `find` for both systems then use:

```
find .  -regex '.*\.ya*ml'
```

Comment: They work on OS X only. The first command fails with the following output on Ubuntu: find: unknown predicate `-E'. The second command does not list any files on Ubuntu.

Comment: I've provided a solution that will work on OSX. Your `find` command in question already works for Ubuntu

Comment: I know, but as I mentioned in my question I am looking for a solution that works on both platforms.

Comment: `find .  -regex '.*\.ya*ml'` will work on both systems